# signInWithPopup doesn't work on android(Ionic 2 + Firebase 3)

Tags: authentication, firebase, ionic-framework

I want to use signInWithPopup in my Ionic 2+Firebase 3 application! It works great on the desktop browser but, when i generate APK for android, it throws network error in auth.js before popup appears. Then, i enter credentials and after that app's blank screen appears. Thanks in advance

```
 var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  // This gives you Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
  this.navCtrl.push(WriteReviewPage);
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  alert(error.message);
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`signInWithPopup()` doesn't work on Ionic/Cordova apps *yet*.

There's a workaround tho, you need to install the [Google Sign-in plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus)

The way that works is that you use the plugin to log the user in, and then you pass those credentials to Firebase.

I made something for [Facebook authentication](https://javebratt.com/ionic-2-firebase-3-facebook/) you'll follow the same process but with the Google plug-in instead.

Comment: Hi, sorry for bringing this question up, but has the problem been solved or we still have to use the workaround you linked?

Comment: Hey @MarinaCooper they added support for Cordova apps: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

But in my experience using the native plugins works best, it's a better experience for the user to show them the account picker so they can sign-in that to have them sign-in through a browser.